# How to pass arguments with slash in Django2 urls

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

I would like to call a Django URL with an argument containing a forward slash. For example, I would like to call `mysite.com/test/` with `'test1/test2'`. (e.g. naively, the url would be `mysite.com/test/test1/test2`)

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('test/<test_arg>/', views.test, name='test'),
]
```

Accessing either of the following fails:

1. `mysite.com/test/test1/test2`
2. `mysite.com/test/test1%2Ftest2` (%2F is the standard URL encoding for forward slash)

with the below error:

Error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in test.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    reader/ test/<test_arg>/
    admin/

The current path, test/test1/test2/, didn't match any of these.
```

I would expect using the path in 1 to fail, but I am surprised the path in 2 fails.

What is the correct way of going about this?

Using Django 2.0.2

Comment: Can you post your view?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The default [path converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) `<test_arg>` (equivalent to `<str:test_arg>`) does not match forward slashes.

Use `<path:test_arg>` to match forward slashes.