# being able to encode slash in url parameters in django template while using url tag to prevent NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm writing a project with python 3.10 and django 4.1

I defined the following route:

```
app_name = 'admin_extend'

urlpatterns = [
    path('add_fav/<str:name>/<str:add_url>/<str:admin_url>/', views.add_fav, name='add_fav'),
]
```

now i have 3 parameters here, `name`, `add_url` and `admin_url`.

both add_url and admin_url contains '/' so i need to be able to escape them in the django template.

this is my code in the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin_extend:add_fav' name=model.name add_url=model.add_url admin_url=model.admin_url %}" class="changelink">{% translate 'Fav' %}</a>
```

lets say the parameters value are name=`'foo'`, add_url=`'/a/b/c/'`, admin_url=`'/c/d/e/'`,
the route fails with `NoReverseMatch`:

```
Reverse for 'add_fav' with keyword arguments '{'name': 'foo', 'add_url': '/a/b/c/', 'admin_url': '/c/d/e/'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin_extend/add_fav/(?P<name>[^/]+)/(?P<add_url>[^/]+)/(?P<admin_url>[^/]+)/\\Z']
```

i tested it and if i provide the parameters without `/` characters then i get no error.

my problem is i really can't find anywhere how to escape these parameters, i googled and checked on stackoverflow a lot

for example i can't use the `{% filter urlencode %}` before and after because the url needs to be validated first and then it will go through the urlencode,

i learned that i can't run python code in these templates so i can't use `urlqoute` from `django.utils.http`

and using urlencode filter in this way is not a correct syntax:

```
{% url 'admin_extend:add_fav' name=(model.name|urlencode) add_url=(model.add_url|urlencode) admin_url=(model.admin_url|urlencode) %}
```

how can I resolve this ?

thanks

Comment: maybe it's a better option to pass the add_url and admin_url as query parameters!

Comment: anyway, maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586991/how-to-pass-arguments-with-slash-in-django2-urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Amrez the solution was more simple than expected, the solution is at [How to pass arguments with slash in Django2 urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586991/how-to-pass-arguments-with-slash-in-django2-urls)

i defined the url argument types as `str`, and i didn't know there is a type called `path` exactly for this case, so just by changing the url pattern the issue was resolved and i didn't need to escape anything, but NOTICE this, original i add `<path:add_url>/<path:admin_url>` since path contains `/` in it, it confused the url parser and both parameters where entered to the `add_url` variable. i needed to change it to `#` instead of `/` and it works properly:

```
path('add_fav/<str:name>/<path:add_url>#<path:admin_url>/', views.add_fav, name='add_fav')
```